# How can I compile the Rabbitmq-c library for iOS 5?

Tags: objective-c, c, rabbitmq, libraries, amqp

I downloaded [the source code for RabbitMQ-C](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c) from GitHub. It's written in C. Can I use this library for iOS 5 apps? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a [wrapper](https://github.com/profmaad/librabbitmq-objc) for ios5, disabled ARC, and rewrote a few vars definitions. It is all working now. :D I might write a bit more about this problem if I find the time.

Comment: I create clone rep for first time on [githab](https://github.com/bimawa/librabbitmq-objC)

Comment: Hi dude, I'm currently using your library for communication with iOS device and windows PC. I successfully created a connection ! But I don't know how to send a string to Windows from my iOS device ! I'm new to rabbitmq, so I don't know much about this. Can you please help me ?

Comment: Midhun MP, do you know how work RabbitMQ? If no, you need create Exchange and create queue, after that you need create bind between queue and Exchange. For receive message on Windows, windows need listes queue with the help of Consumer. And now you can push message to Exchange With class [AMQPExchange](https://github.com/bimawa/librabbitmq-objC/blob/master/AMQPExchange.m) look at on method publishMessage.

Comment: Thanks dude :) One more question. I created a queue and exchange. Now how can I connect queue and exchange using bind?

Comment: AMQPQueue  has method bindToExchange

Comment: I done that. Thank you ... Thank you very much dude :) Thanks alot. You helped me alot. :)

Comment: hey @Bimawa, i m also using your library, but when i tried to login with "guest" , "guest" (username, pwd) , application just hangs,while executing statement,

result = recv(state->sockfd, state->sock_inbound_buffer.bytes,state->sock_inbound_buffer.len, 0);

Comment: @MidhunMP, r u able to login and send/recv messages ??

Comment: @Matrix, hi. Mb you not set virtual host like "/"? recv forever in infinity loop. I fix that issue, but not test and not push on github.. mb later.

Comment: @Matrix: Yes, I successfuly done that :)

Comment: hi @Bimawa, i hv set "/" as a virtual host.

Comment: @Bimawa, what should be the values of : bindingkey,routingkey and queue ? can they be any string ??

Comment: @MidhunMP, what should be the values of : bindingkey,routingkey and queue ? can they be any string ??

Comment: @Matrix: Yes. But the it should be the same one is using in your rabbitmq server application.

Comment: @Matrix study RabbitMQ documentation. You must know what is bindingkey,routingkey and queue...

Comment: i am able to login and send-recv message. but for that i have passed predefined queue name. Is there any way so that i don't need to pass queue name, it create dynamic queue on server. passing nil or @"" is also not working in queue name, @Bimawa ??

Comment: i am looking for: queue should be dynamically created from client side to server, any idea @MidhunMP ?

Comment: @Matrix: Currently I'm doing that. I have wrote a method which takes the queue name as parameter and create a queue with that name. Also creates a queue at windows side also.

Comment: @MidhunMP, i m using : 
 AMQPQueue *queue = [[AMQPQueue alloc] initWithName:<queue_name> onChannel:channel];
to create a queue, but when i bind exchange with this queue, it is saying that no such queue found on server.

any idea how to create queue on server ?

Comment: and with another method for AMQPQueue , i m getting error message like: AMQPException: Failed to declare queue: No such file or directory.

Comment: @Matrix: I didn't saw any error messages till now. The one issue I faced was exchange type can't be altered. Means cannot re-define a fanout exchange as direct.
1) Check whether you installed RabbitMQ properly on your server 2) Check whether erlang is installed 3) Check you specified the ip correctly on your iOS app. 4) If you are using windows check for firewall issues.

Comment: this is my sample code:

    AMQPConnection *connection = [[AMQPConnection alloc] init];
    [connection connectToHost:<hostname> onPort:5672 error:&error] ? NSLog(@"Connected to host"):NSLog(@"not connected to host");

[connection loginAsUser:@"guest" withPasswort:@"guest"
                        onVHost:@"/" error:&error1];

Comment: AMQPChannel *channel = [connection openChannel];
 AMQPExchange * exchange = [[AMQPExchange alloc] initExchangeWithName:<exchangename>
                                                               onChannel:channel];
 
    AMQPQueue *queue = [[AMQPQueue alloc] initWithName:<any queue_name> onChannel:channel];

Comment: [queue bindToExchange:exchange withKey:<key_name> error:&error3];

 AMQPConsumer *consumer = [[AMQPConsumer alloc] initForQueue:queue onChannel:&channel
                                            useAcknowledgements:YES
                                                    isExclusive:NO
                                           receiveLocalMessages:NO
                                                          error:&error2
                                                       deepLoop:5];

Comment: AMQPConsumerThread *consumerThread = [[AMQPConsumerThread alloc] initWithConsumer:consumer delegate:(id)self nameThread:@"my_thread"];
    [consumerThread start];

Comment: any thing you found wrong here, @MidhunMP ??

Comment: @Bimawa, any thing you found wrong in sample code ??

Comment: This method: "- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)theName onChannel:(AMQPChannel *)theChannel error:(NSError **)error" not declare queue. First for use this method your Queue must has been declared in RabbitMq. For declare queue on rabbit you need use this method: - (id)initWithName:(NSString*)theName onChannel:(AMQPChannel*)theChannel isPassive:(BOOL)passive isExclusive:(BOOL)exclusive isDurable:(BOOL)durable getsAutoDeleted:(BOOL)autoDelete error:(NSError **)error

Comment: Now i better understand how work rabbit-mq, and latter we make powerful library for ios.

Comment: @Bimawa, when i call that method which u mentioned : 

- (id)initWithName:(NSString)theName onChannel:(AMQPChannel*)theChannel isPassive:(BOOL)passive isExclusive:(BOOL)exclusive isDurable:(BOOL)durable getsAutoDeleted:(BOOL)autoDelete error:(NSError **)error

Comment: i m getting error:
19:48:05.763 RabbitMQ Sample2[10138:11303] AMQPException: Failed to bind queue to exchange: No such file or directory
2013-06-04 19:48:05.764 RabbitMQ Sample2[10138:11303] Connection: <AMQPConnection: 0x756b6d0>
2013-06-04 19:48:05.764 RabbitMQ Sample2[10138:11303] AMQPException: Failed to start consumer: No such file or directory

Comment: @Bimawa, is it related to server environment configuration ??

Comment: @Matrix noo, oh man. Mb you not declare exchange? You mast bind queue only to exchange. Declare exchange first, then declare queue after that bind queue to echange. Connect consumer to queue ... "receiving messages :D HF".

Comment: debugged today, the problem is i am able to create a queue and exchange, but when trying to bind exchange with queue, some library exception is thrown.
any idea @Bimawa ??

Comment: @Bimawa, i think its a same issue which i m facing: https://github.com/bimawa/AMQProtocol/issues/1

Comment: Oh yea... i understood you. It's true, this bug, maybe, relation with threads. But i need a lot of time for fix it... Now i work at new library fully native for objective-c.

Comment: i push my last commit. But i dont know it's solve your troubles or not.

Comment: hey @Bimawa, i have fixed that problem. everything works fine now.

Comment: thanks for your help @Bimawa :) i will also update in github link, how i fixed it.

Comment: @Matrix Cool i'll be wait :) thx

Comment: @Bimawa, I would like to use your wrapper but in IOS. Is this possible? If so what should I do? There is no cocoa.h on ios and there are some other errors. maybe we can make a new question about this. If I get it to work I am happy to share a working ios project for xcode.

Comment: @fellowworldcitizen My wrapper is very crude, I had the idea to rewrite everything on pure objective-c, but is not available at this time. Now it's work on socket.h on C based. It's class can't work with 3G nets and not support dynamic switch net connection. If you need you can start new project for creating objective-c client for rabbit-mq. If i found a time i can help you.

Comment: @Bimawa, Thankyou for the quick response. Yes I need support for 3G as well and it should be over SSL. How come this thread is about ios 5 then? Could you contact me at: joris [at] trackbyte.nl?

Comment: @fellowworldcitizen i send mail for you.